# How to embed SSIS designer in WinForms application

Tags: .net, winforms, ssis

I have a piece of software that runs SSIS packages. It is written in c# and runs WinForms for UI.
I got a request from the client to allow SSIS package editing via a control embedded in the application itself. 
Since SSIS is just an XML it should be possible, is there a reusable designer control for SSIS. 
How would you approach this.

Comment: Would it help to create UI Controls to get values for conditions and pass it as parameters to SSIS package?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any UI support for integrating SSIS designer, but I would suggest taking a look at Business Intelligence Markup Language (BIML). Maybe your clients could specify the changes to the packages to another UI application and that input could be used to compile BIML and create the new package? This is something I have not worked with, but would love to see in action. Just my thoughts.

The problem with manually modifying the package is that BIDS keeps a lot of extra information in terms of "development" and XML wont make much sense. The ID's might change and what not. It might be just too much to program for I guess. I could be wrong here though.

Comment: I will research this possibility - do you know of any library that would render an image of the package or BIML?